# Downloading file from Google Drive

Tags: python

I'm trying to download a file from Google Drive using `gdown` as follows:

```
file_id = url.split('=')[-1]
gdrive_url = f'https://drive.google.com/uc?id={file_id}'
                
output_path = os.path.join(extract_to, 'file.tgz')
gdown.download(gdrive_url, output_path, quiet=False)
```

However, I keep getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_431/1011135980.py in <cell line: 5>()
      3 extract_to = '../fonts_data/fonts_recommend/third_party/adobe_research'
      4 
----> 5 download_and_extract(zip_url, extract_to, gdrive=True)

/tmp/ipykernel_431/1160197662.py in download_and_extract(url, extract_to, gdrive)
     34                     tar_ref.extractall(path=extract_to)
     35             else:
---> 36                 raise ValueError('Unsupported file extension for: ' + url)
     37 
     38     print(f"Extracted contents to {extract_to}")

ValueError: Unsupported file extension for: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10GRqLu6-1JPXI8rcq23S4-4AhB6On-L6
```

No matter what I try. Not sure what I missing. This is the file URL (which I can download locally):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10GRqLu6-1JPXI8rcq23S4-4AhB6On-L6/view

Comment: Does the issue persist if you try with an uncompressed file of a similar size? If you check the FAQ section [here](https://pypi.org/project/gdown/), it may be because "Google restricts access to a file when the download is concentrated" but I am hoping the dev means "compressed". Hopefully it's just that as the `gdown` dev offers a solution in the same FAQ entry.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the `gdown` library. You can try running the sample code below to download the file from the attached GG Drive link

```py
import gdown

url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/10GRqLu6-1JPXI8rcq23S4-4AhB6On-L6/view'
url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + url.split('/')[-2]
output = 'file_downloaded.tz'
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing and it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to be correct. However, the file you are attempting to download may be exceptionally large, and there might be numerous users simultaneously trying to download it programmatically. In such cases, you may encounter an error similar to the one I am currently observing:

```
FileURLRetrievalError: Failed to retrieve file url:

    Too many users have viewed or downloaded this file recently. Please
    try accessing the file again later. If the file you are trying to
    access is particularly large or is shared with many people, it may
    take up to 24 hours to be able to view or download the file. If you
    still can't access a file after 24 hours, contact your domain
    administrator.

     You may still be able to access the file from the browser:

    https://drive.google.com/uc?id=10GRqLu6-1JPXI8rcq23S4-4AhB6On-L6

    but Gdown can't. Please check connections and permissions.
```